# D3.JS: How to transform circle's cx and cy attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transform

I have a lot of circles appended to and svg using this function

```
function makeCircles(){
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(companies)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 7)
        .attr("class", "company")
        .attr("cx",0)
        .attr("cy",0);
}
```

I have another function that transforms the cx and cy along an x and y scale. I pass this function the figures in the array of data (ie companies) I want to use in calculating the cx and cy

```
function moveCircles(theX, theY){
    svg.selectAll("circle.company")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("cx",function(d,i){return x(d[theX])})
        .attr("cy",function(d,i){return y(d[theY])});
}
```

So in my script I first call `makeCircles();`
Then I call `moveCircles("marketCapX","marketCapY");`
And this seems to work fine. It moves the circles in the upper left corner to their spots on the svg over one second.
But then I have a button that calls `moveCircles()` again. This time passing new data, for example: `moveCircles("femaleX","femaleY")`. But this time the circles go to the end of where the last circle was when I called `moveCircles("marketCapX","marketCapY")`.  I want the circles to rearrange themselves based on their new data. How do I get this to work?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: It an array of objects, each object is a circle, it has keys and properties that I'm trying to use to calculate the cx and cy: 
[{companyname: "Apple Inc.",
female: 0.29,
femaleIndex: 69,
femaleX: 3.5,
femaleY: 25.5,
idcompany: 13040,
marketCapIndex: 0,
marketCapX: 0.5,
marketCapY: 0.5,
mktcap: 646809,
ticker: "AAPL",
unrelated: 0.86},....ect

Comment: Looks like it should work. Could you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: Ok, I figured this out. Should've mentioned. But before I call moveCircles(); I update the data (companies) with the number to be parsed by the x and y scales with these functions: sortData("mktcap");
      addXYIndexToData("marketCapX","marketCapY","marketCapIndex");

Comment: This function loops through the data adding the number to be parsed by x, y scales...function addXYIndexToData(theX, theY, theIndex){
for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
if(i % numOfCirclesInRow === 0 && i !== 0){
xCounter = 0.5;
yCounter= yCounter+1;
}companies[i][theX] = xCounter;
companies[i][theY] = yCounter;
companies[i][theIndex] = i;xCounter = xCounter+1;
 }; }

Comment: ..the problem was I wasnt rebasing the numbers to zero (or my case 0.5) before I run this function